# Remove / Disable extension from Magento Connect

Tags: magento2, module, magento-1, magento-connect

I have my developer account in Magento Connect. I have two extensions uploaded and now I want one of them to be `disabled or removed` from my developer listing.

In the `Versions` tab, I try changing the `Show on Frontend` value set to `No`, but no luck.

How can I achieve this ?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go to edit the extension there is a setting called Extension Status. Changing this to Offline will disable the public listing. There is also Deleted which I haven't tried yet.

[image: Extension status]

Comment: What is recommended ? Offline or Delete ?

Comment: Depends on your indentions here - but if you know that you don't want to use it again in the future you use Delete. If you are unsure, Offline until you are sure. I believe it is still possible to download the extension via Connect if it is marked as offline (if you know the extension code) it will just disable the listing on magento.com.